# Help identifying brand of bicycle

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm attempting to identify the brand of bicycle that is shown in this picture.  Unfortunately these are the best quality I can find.  When I zoom in the letters are too grainy to see.

[image: The only picture I can get...]

Comment: Nothing distinctive, fairly recent vintage, not the cheapest possible, but "department store" quality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't tell.  The threaded stem, cheap looking fork, along with the warning sticker on the crank not to thread the wrong side pedals in the wrong crank arm, along with the plastic chainguard on the crank, all point to it being a department store bike.

Comment: Don't forget the forward facing rear reflector!

Comment: That was my suspicion as well.  It looked pretty budget.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's a BSO ... a Bike-Shaped Object.